# Does Scrum prescribe work item statuses and their meanings?

Tags: agile, scrum, azure-devops

At work, we're using Scrum with Azure DevOps (specifically using the Scrum process to manage our items) to run our sprints.

My question is, does the Scrum process within Azure Boards or Scrum in general prescribe product backlog item (PBI) statuses. Specifically that they *must* be marked as `Committed` when brought into a sprint backlog.

I've read through the [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html), and that Scrum only refers to commitment to a sprint goal, and not specifically prescribing work item statuses.

This section in the guide, specifically the bolded sentences seem to align with the above thought.

> Scrum is simple. Try it as is and determine if its philosophy, theory, and structure help to achieve goals and create value. **The Scrum framework is purposefully incomplete, only defining the parts required to implement Scrum theory**. Scrum is built upon by the collective intelligence of the people using it. **Rather than provide people with detailed instructions, the rules of Scrum guide their relationships and interactions.**
>
> **Various processes, techniques and methods can be employed within the framework.**

In typing up this question, I've also found a bit of documentation on Azure Boards help which refers to the Scrum process items, that suggests there is no requirement for items to have a specific status for the sprint (specifically the Product Backlog Item workflow).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/scrum-process-workflow?view=azure-devops#track-progress

Specifically the bullet point that states:

> The team updates the status to **Committed** when they decide to commit to working on it during the sprint

The reason for my question is, our team is being told by a tech lead that these PBIs need to be set to `Committed` as part of Scrum, and not doing so would be to not do Scrum, which seems to be made up.

**TL;DR** - Does Scrum prescribe work item statuses (specifically about PBIs) when being brought into sprint backlog, and is not marking PBIs as `Committed` in a sprint backlog breaking Scrum?

Comment: This is a people problem, not a procedural problem.  If your tech lead won't entertain ideas about how to improve the process, take those ideas to their boss.

Comment: I know, the question is specifically about whether or not Scrum defines the item statuses though. The boss is reliant on what the person says so sides with them, hence I'm not asking for a solution to the people problem, just if my understanding is along the right lines in terms of Scrum and work items.

Comment: You won't win this argument with logic or appeal to authority.  You'll win it (if "winning it" is actually the right words) by demonstrating value in your point of view to someone who has the authority to make actual changes.

Comment: I'm not trying to win the argument by appeal to authority, that is a lost cause as the authority that someone who has the authority to make changes refers to, is the person in question. As stated I'm being told something that is inconsistent with my understanding of Scrum, and I'm trying to make sure my understanding isn't in violation of it by objective means.

Comment: The authority I'm referring to is the scrum process itself. It doesn't matter if it's objective or not; the person preventing you from fixing it won't care. Go see their boss.

Comment: @vman, I guess you are not visiting the Done stories every day. Have you tried to find out if there is a reason, other than "(I believe that) Scrum requires it", why the tech lead believes it is a good idea to visit the not-started stories? It could be his way of reminding the team that there is more work to do and that they shouldn't slack off.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, that's correct. We just go through items in the sprint backlog where we start from the top and go all the way to the bottom. Since every story is "Committed" unless Done, whoever is assigned to the story being looked at will either provide the 3 answers (yesterday, today, impediments) or say it's not started yet. The tech leads' belief is that all stories must be set to "Committed" when brought into the sprint backlog, regardless if they are being worked on, as without it, isn't Scrum. If there is reprioritisation needed we can always discuss that at the end of stand-up.

Comment: Why does a "tech lead" have any say in this? There is no "tech lead" position in Scrum. Where is your Scrum Master? *They* should be the authority to ask about all matters "Scrum". It seems you are using a tool, without actually using the method.

Comment: @nvoigt we don't have a Scrum Master (SM) currently. That's my point about the TL, they are acting as the ultimate authority on this, even though the rest of the team see it differently. We're being told X, but when we read about Scrum it says Y.

Comment: If you don't have a Scrum Master, you are not doing Scrum, period. There is no point in discussing whether details in your tickets conform to Scrum, if you don't even have the basic minimum. When you read about Scrum, does it not say you should have a Scrum Master? It does not mean your method of organizing work is bad per se, it just means it's *not Scrum*. Anybody calling it Scrum is wrong. That is the *one* rule about Scrum: don't call if Scrum if you don't follow it's rules.

Answer (score 4):

The Scrum framework doesn't offer too many states for Product Backlog Items. Through the act of refinement, the team makes Product Backlog Items "ready for selection in a Sprint Planning Event". Then, during the Sprint, Product Backlog Items meet the Definition of Done and there is a new product Increment. Everything else is up to the discretion of the team.

Some Scrum Teams have had success drawing on Kanban techniques. One of the principles of Kanban is to visualize the workflow, and Scrum Teams will do this by representing their workflow on a board and using that board to make the state of the work visible to the team and key stakeholders. However, the workflow needs to reflect the team's way of working, so each organization or team will have their own workflow. Without a much deeper understanding of the team's way of working, it's hard to say what your workflow or your board should look like, if you decide to apply this technique.

It seems like this could be an XY Problem, however.

I don't think this will help you with ineffective Daily Scrums. It seems like you're using your Daily Scrum to report on the status of the work instead of planning your next immediate step to get closer to achieving the Sprint Goal. There are better techniques out there for carrying out a Daily Scrum. Although a board and good visualizations of the work could help, you would still need to focus on how to make plans to progress the work rather than updating the board or discussing the status of the work itself.

I would also recommend against calling work items committed. I don't think that the Scrum workflow states described in the Azure DevOps documentation are appropriate or consistent with the Scrum framework. It may make sense to have a workflow that is inclusive of the initial idea through a well-refined idea and then to completion, the use of terms like "approved" and "committed" aren't that consistent with the Scrum framework.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't discuss the backlog in the daily stand up at all. You should have selected the items that are in the sprint at the start and confine your daily stand up to

1. what you did yesterday (ie. task worked on/completed)
2. what you will do today (ie. task from the sprint board you are picking up, or continuing)
3. any blockers. (ie. I need more info on this spec/can someone nag this other team etc)

It sounds like your suggestion is reasonable and should be adopted. the whole point of retros is so that you can change the way you are working.

Teams adopting scrum for the first time should be careful not to change the rules just out of resistance to change. But there's no reason to veto a minor change to the process like this.

Comment: The confusing terminology is from Azure Boards. Even though it is called the Product Backlog Item (PBI), in my question it is an item in the current sprint. We just go through each item even if work hasn't yet started on it, which is what my suggestion aimed to cut down on.

Comment: maybe we have a different setup or something but we use AZDO and have a separate backlog and sprints.

Answer (score 1):

> ... our team is being told by a tech lead that these PBIs need to be set to "Committed" as part of Scrum, and not doing so would be to not do Scrum ...

Your tech lead is combining two things: committing to work as a sprint deliverable (which Scrum *does* prescribe) and the work item status your particular team uses to reflect the scrum process in a tool. This illustrates the difference between "process" and "procedure."

Your scrum **process** dictates that the team must commit to a deliverable each sprint. Your team **procedure** when using Azure DevOps is to change the state of those product backlog items to "Committed" once the team has decided to make it a goal.

Don't confuse how you use a tool with how a development methodology should be implemented by your team. The tool provides the means to reflect the abstract Scrum process in the real world, and your team has decided to use work item statuses to reflect a crucial part of the scrum process: committing to work.

Comment: The team hasn't decided to use the work item statuses specifically to reflect the scrum process. We use the sprint goal and make a commitment to achieving that, not statuses. The item statuses are imposed on us by the tech lead, whereas the team is fine with having items at a minimum `Approved` in the sprint.

Comment: @vman: ok, replace "team" with "tech lead" and my answer still stands.

Comment: Matter of fact, Scrum Teams no longer "commit" to a result, they "forecast" it. This has been a change in the 20**11** Scrum guide, so it's not been "Commitment" for longer than a decade now. But that does not invalidate the answer, it's just wording, showing that what the OP does has to do with the tooling, not the process. The tooling is behind (or wrong) about it.

Answer (score 0):

So many red flags, where to start?

As you have found out, Scrum does not offer any tooling. It describes a *process*. You *can* use tooling if it helps you, but you don't have to.

So the claim that it isn't Scrum unless you do something specific in third party tool like Azure is profoundly stupid. You can do Scrum with 3 Stacks of assorted notes on paper. You don't need a computer at all. If you do it by the guide, it's still very much Scrum.

You mentioned in a comment that you do not *have* a Scrum Master. That is a **basic minimum** of Scrum. Who cares about states in a tool if you fail so fundamentally at implementing Scrum?

Then there is the issue of your "daily", that is basically not a Scrum team coordination meeting, but a daily status report for a supervisor. That is not what a daily Scrum meeting is about. It is not about going through all the tickets. And it is not about answering three questions. See [this answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/33617/how-can-a-scrum-daily-not-be-a-status-pull/33625#33625) about what a daily Scrum meeting should be like, to actually be useful as intended, to foster communication and collaboration, not report a status or go through checklists.

So to sum this up, you are not doing Scrum. On *so* many levels.

I'm not saying that what your boss or tech leads want is bad. Or that Scrum would be better. Who knows. But **it is not Scrum**. The reason I'm so adamant about it is that what you write here is the precursor to another one of those "we did Scrum and is was so bad" stories. You didn't do Scrum. At all. If it was bad, then it wasn't because of Scrum.

Turning this argument around for a minute: whatever you want to achieve, there is no point in finding assistance in the Scrum guide. Because you are not doing Scrum. Focus on how doing something differently helps you do a better job. If you don't like what you are doing, propose a better way. Not based on a theory, like the Scrum guide, but based on an actual thing happening in your company. If you think the meeting could be shorter, by going round per person instead of per ticket, propose that for example.